# Integration over triangles equal to zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $T \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the triangle $0<y<x<1$ and $f \in L^2(T)$ be such that
$$\int_0^x f(x,y) dy=0, \quad \mbox{ for almost every } x \in (0,1).$$
Does it imply that $f=0$ in $T$ ? If not, what is a counterexample ?

Comment: No. There can be some points f(x,y) is not zero, as long as the set of those points is of Lebesgue measure zero

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your answer, can you give me a simple counterexample then ?

Comment: Say that for all but (1/2,1/2) f is zero, but on (1/2,1/2) f is 1

Comment: This does not work, $f=0$ means $f=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Then likely yes, since the set is of measure zero...

Comment: In the case where the domain is the rectangle, $[0,1]^2$, you can take $f(x,y) = \pm 1$ depending on whether $y > 1/2$. This would satisfy the condition, right? So try to build a similar example for the triangle.

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed, $f(x,y)=\pm 1$ depending on whether $y>x/2$ does the job. Have a good day